# How to use Microsoft Bot Framework web chat in Angular5 application

Tags: angular, botframework, web-chat

I need a way to embed web chat in my angular 5 application. I have tried the non react website way described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat  and it works.

Is there a way to use the components only rather than loading the entire js file to get the chat window in my Angualar 5 app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install the BotFramework-WebChat version greater than `0.10.7`, you can directly use the BotFramework-WebChat in ng application.

- Install the webchat sdk: `npm install botframework-webchat`
- fill the style files in `.angular-cli.json` file:

  ```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/botframework-webchat/botchat.css",
    "../node_modules/botframework-webchat/botchat-fullwindow.css"
  ],
  ```
- Try the sample in component as discussed at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/478:

  ```
  import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
  import {App} from "botframework-webchat";
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div id="bot-chat-container" #botWindow></div>`,
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild("botWindow") botWindowElement: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(): void {
      App({
        directLine: {secret: 'secret goes here'},
        user: {id: 'user'},
        bot: {id: 'bot'},
      }, this.botWindowElement.nativeElement)
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: FYI this will bundle the react framework and will dramatically increase the bundle filesize